# Prediction.io training unresponsive

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, prediction, predictionio

I am using [SimilarProduct](https://templates.prediction.io/PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-similarproduct) template of `prediction.io` Inserted 16 thousand products, 70 thousand users and 1.6 million view events.

`pio build` is done successfully but in `pio train` it goes unresponsive at stage 13 since I have tried 3 times at waited for 6 to 7 hours but it stuck at the stage 13 below is the logs

```
[INFO] [Console$] Using existing engine manifest JSON at /home/dau/PredictionIO/similar_product/manifest.json
[INFO] [Runner$] Submission command: /home/dau/PredictionIO/vendors/spark-1.6.0/bin/spark-submit --class io.prediction.workflow.CreateWorkflow --jars file:/home/dau/PredictionIO/similar_product/target/scala-2.10/template-scala-parallel-similarproduct-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT-deps.jar,file:/home/dau/PredictionIO/similar_product/target/scala-2.10/template-scala-parallel-similarproduct_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --files file:/home/dau/PredictionIO/conf/log4j.properties,file:/home/dau/PredictionIO/vendors/hbase-1.1.2/conf/hbase-site.xml --driver-class-path /home/dau/PredictionIO/conf:/home/dau/PredictionIO/lib/postgresql-9.4-1204.jdbc41.jar:/home/dau/PredictionIO/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:/home/dau/PredictionIO/vendors/hbase-1.1.2/conf file:/home/dau/PredictionIO/lib/pio-assembly-0.9.6.jar --engine-id TvPK9sthW8Hjh6lyz0PRqtCb6IIzOLSF --engine-version 9c974b7a0cc9a0a9c97387bbacb6486db3ebb738 --engine-variant file:/home/dau/PredictionIO/similar_product/engine.json --verbosity 0 --json-extractor Both --env PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_HBASE_TYPE=hbase,PIO_ENV_LOADED=1,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_NAME=pio_meta,PIO_FS_BASEDIR=/home/dau/.pio_store,PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_HBASE_HOME=/home/dau/PredictionIO/vendors/hbase-1.1.2,PIO_HOME=/home/dau/PredictionIO,PIO_FS_ENGINESDIR=/home/dau/.pio_store/engines,PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_LOCALFS_PATH=/home/dau/.pio_store/models,PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE=elasticsearch,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_SOURCE=ELASTICSEARCH,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_SOURCE=LOCALFS,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDATA_NAME=pio_event,PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_HOME=/home/dau/PredictionIO/vendors/elasticsearch-1.7.3,PIO_FS_TMPDIR=/home/dau/.pio_store/tmp,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_NAME=pio_model,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDATA_SOURCE=HBASE,PIO_CONF_DIR=/home/dau/PredictionIO/conf,PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_LOCALFS_TYPE=localfs
[INFO] [Engine] Extracting datasource params...
[INFO] [WorkflowUtils$] No 'name' is found. Default empty String will be used.
[INFO] [Engine] Datasource params: (,DataSourceParams(rw_store))
[INFO] [Engine] Extracting preparator params...
[INFO] [Engine] Preparator params: (,Empty)
[INFO] [Engine] Extracting serving params...
[INFO] [Engine] Serving params: (,Empty)
[WARN] [Utils] Your hostname, dau-lap resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.43.91 instead (on interface wlan0)
[WARN] [Utils] Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
[INFO] [Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@192.168.43.91:40349]
[INFO] [Engine$] EngineWorkflow.train
[INFO] [Engine$] DataSource: com.company.DataSource@7cfb8e98
[INFO] [Engine$] Preparator: com.company.Preparator@1ec88aa1
[INFO] [Engine$] AlgorithmList: List(com.company.ALSAlgorithm@3030836d)
[INFO] [Engine$] Data sanity check is on.
[WARN] [TableInputFormatBase] Cannot resolve the host name for dau-lap/127.0.1.1 because of javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]; remaining name '1.1.0.127.in-addr.arpa'
[WARN] [TableInputFormatBase] Cannot resolve the host name for dau-lap/127.0.1.1 because of javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]; remaining name '1.1.0.127.in-addr.arpa'
[WARN] [TableInputFormatBase] Cannot resolve the host name for dau-lap/127.0.1.1 because of javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]; remaining name '1.1.0.127.in-addr.arpa'
[WARN] [TableInputFormatBase] Cannot resolve the host name for dau-lap/127.0.1.1 because of javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]; remaining name '1.1.0.127.in-addr.arpa'
[INFO] [Engine$] com.company.TrainingData does not support data sanity check. Skipping check.
[INFO] [Engine$] com.company.PreparedData does not support data sanity check. Skipping check.
[WARN] [TableInputFormatBase] Cannot resolve the host name for dau-lap/127.0.1.1 because of javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]; remaining name '1.1.0.127.in-addr.arpa'
[WARN] [TableInputFormatBase] Cannot resolve the host name for dau-lap/127.0.1.1 because of javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]; remaining name '1.1.0.127.in-addr.arpa'
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.    
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 0 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 3055 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 3055 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 3055 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 222 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 222 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 416 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 0 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[Stage 13:>                                                         (0 + 1) / 2][INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 0 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 484 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 222 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 414 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[INFO] [ALSAlgorithm] Couldn't convert nonexistent item ID 513 to Int index.
[Stage 13:=============================>                            (1 + 0) / 2]
```

Here is `engine.json`

```
{
  "id": "default",
  "description": "Default settings",
  "engineFactory": "com.company.SimilarProductEngine",
  "datasource": {
    "params" : {
      "appName": "store"
    }
  },
  "algorithms": [
    {
      "name": "als",
      "params": {
        "rank": 10,
        "numIterations" : 20,
        "lambda": 0.01,
        "seed": 3
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You've not shown your code/command line. You've lots of warnings - are those non-existent line items an issue? Does it work on a smaller dataset? Etc, etc. Basically, you're not giving us much to work with here...

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I have updated engine.json here. I have used simple commands like pio build and pio train. Complementary purchase template worked successfully on the same dataset. Please let me know what other info you want

Comment: And what about a small data set for this template?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I will try it too then inform you

Comment: Looks like other people have had this problem; https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/predictionio-user/a00QVzPIvuM  and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/predictionio-user/sTgc_AnClXo The second link suggests setting up a standalone Spark cluster helps a lot..

Answer (score 0):

you should define three types of events.user, item and view event.i think you define view event on an specific items that does not have their corresponding item.